# Change count to probability in this histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm struggling to change the count to probability in the following histogram without messing the red area. Also, how to align the 1,10 with the rest of the numbers on the x-axis?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
nrep = 10000
scientific <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==1e+0, "1", ifelse(x==1e+1,"10",parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("1e+", "10^", scales::scientific_format()(x))))))
}
bw <- 0.05
mx=rf(nrep,5,2)
df = tibble(x = mx)
ggplot(df,aes(x)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "#1380A1") + 
geom_histogram(data=df %>% filter(x < 10^(-1) + 1.15*bw), binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "red") +
geom_density(aes(y = bw*after_stat(count)), color="blue") +
scale_x_continuous(trans="log10", breaks = 10^seq(-1, 5, by = 1), labels = scientific)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your code. To convert `geom_histogram` from counts to density, you need to add `y = after_stat(density)` to the `aes()`. Then you can just highlight part of your histogram inside `aes()` using `fill` condition. See https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight/issues/106#issuecomment-477896518

Comment: @atsyplenkov Thanks. I edited the code. It should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the scale from count to density in the layers `geom_histogram`. In the first histogram, you can do it using `after_stat(density)` which is equivalent to `after_stat(count/sum(count))/bw`. However, the same procedure does not work in the second histogram because `sum(count)` is different when you subset a dataset. If you do it, the second histogram will be on a different scale.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
nrep = 10000
scientific <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==1e+0, "1", ifelse(x==1e+1,"10",parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("1e+", "10^", scales::scientific_format()(x))))))
}
bw <- 0.05
mx=rf(nrep,5,2)

df = tibble(x = mx) 
pdf <- df %>% filter(x < 10^(-1) + 1.15*bw)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df,
                 aes(x = x, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)/bw),
                 binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "#1380A1") + 
  geom_histogram(data = pdf, 
                 aes(x = x, y = after_stat(count/sum(count)/bw),
                 binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "red") +
  geom_density(data = df, 
               aes(x = x), color="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10", breaks = 10^seq(-1, 5, by = 1), 
                     labels = scientific)
```

[image]

Therefore, you need to calculate the density with the same denominator from the first histogram, which is defined as `nrep`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
nrep = 10000
scientific <- function(x){
  ifelse(x==1e+0, "1", ifelse(x==1e+1,"10",parse(text=gsub("[+]", "", gsub("1e+", "10^", scales::scientific_format()(x))))))
}
bw <- 0.05
mx=rf(nrep,5,2)

df = tibble(x = mx) 
pdf <- df %>% filter(x < 10^(-1) + 1.15*bw)
ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = df,
                 aes(x = x, y = after_stat(density)),
                 binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "#1380A1") + 
  geom_histogram(data = pdf, 
                 aes(x = x, y = after_stat(count/nrep)/bw),
                 binwidth=bw, color="white", fill = "red") +
  geom_density(data = df, 
               aes(x = x), color="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10", breaks = 10^seq(-1, 5, by = 1), 
                     labels = scientific)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to align 1 and 10 on the x-axis with the rest of the numbers? When I changed 10^0 and 10^1 to 1 and 10, they are positioned slightly higher than the rest.

Comment: I do not think it is feasible to posit labels for selected ticks in a different alignment from the overall label alignment for x-axis.